# Accessibility traversal order in recyclerview scrolls horizontally

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility

`View`: Parent View is `RelativeLayout` - I have set accessibility traversal order inside `RelativeLayout`.

This `View` is part of `RecyclerView` which scrolls horizontally.

> Traversal order of accessibility view items works as expected in order for the first ViewHolder of RecyclerView where screen is visible. But when focusing on next item using swipe action, it traverse randomly.
>
> How to maintain accessibility traverse order in recyclerview which scrolls horizontally?

Below is my `View` which is part of `RecyclerView`.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
  >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/launch_product_image_size"
    android:contentDescription="@string/product_image"
    android:focusable="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/day_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image_product"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@+id/name_txt"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="@{item.launchDate != null}"
    bind:date="@{item.launchDate}"
    bind:format="@{Constants.DAY_DISPLAY_FORMAT}"
    tools:text="MON"
    style="@style/Display"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/month_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/day_txt"
    android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@+id/day_txt"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="@{item.launchDate != null}"
    bind:date="@{item.launchDate}"
    bind:format="@{Constants.DATE_DISPLAY_FORMAT}"
    tools:text="APR 24"
    style="@style/Display.Small"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/day_txt"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/day_txt"
    android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@+id/image_product"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="@{item.name}"
    tools:text="adidas Yeezy boost 350 Triple White…."
    style="@style/Body.Small"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you fixed it?

Comment: @user2462737 Nah, it's not yet fixed. Same random traversal using accessibility once the view is accessible full.